# Hard typecasts in ctypes possible? int -> "pointer to struct" for example

Tags: python, ctypes

I have am inside a callback that allows me to access the pointers passed to it as `int` (i.e. the Python `type()` function returns `int`).

What so I have to do if I want convert this into a pointer of a `struct` whose layout I know and can define as a `ctypes` class. Say I have this already:

```
class data_t(Structure):
  _fields = [ ("foo", c_int), ("bar", c_wchar_p), ("baz", c_char_p) ]
```

How can a variable `x` for which `type(x)` gives the output `int` now be cast into a pointer to the above `struct` type?

**The gist:** I have no influence on the declaration of the callback function or the declaration of the arguments I get to see, so I need some way to get from the Python `int` type to a `ctypes` pointer and access the `struct` members from there ...

This is Python 2.6, but I reckon most 2.x will be similar enough at least. I can't get rid of this version requirement as it is embedded into a product that requires *this particular* Python version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ctypes.cast`, or just declare the callback to return a `POINTER(data_t)`.  Examples of both below and tested on Python 2.7 and Python 3.2:

#### test DLL code (Windows)

```
typedef struct data {
    int foo;
    wchar_t* bar;
    char* baz;
} data_t;

typedef void (*CALLBACK)(data_t* p);

CALLBACK g_callback = 0;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void set_callback(CALLBACK f)
{
    g_callback = f;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void call_callback()
{
    data_t data;
    data.foo = 123;
    data.bar = L"马克";
    data.baz = "Mark";
    g_callback(&data);
}
```

#### Python

```
from ctypes import *

class data_t(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("foo", c_int),
        ("bar", c_wchar_p),
        ("baz", c_char_p)]

dll = CDLL('test')

@CFUNCTYPE(None,c_int)
def callback(n):
    p = cast(n,POINTER(data_t)).contents
    print(p.foo,p.bar,p.baz)

@CFUNCTYPE(None,POINTER(data_t))
def callback2(n):
    p = n.contents
    print(p.foo,p.bar,p.baz)

dll.set_callback(callback)
dll.call_callback()

dll.set_callback(callback2)
dll.call_callback()
```

#### Output

```
123 马克 b'Mark'
123 马克 b'Mark'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and +1 for that already. I'll give it a try after some sleep and then accept it or ask back :)

Comment: oddly enough this gives me an access violation in `python.exe` ... still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Using the exact code?  One usual cause when dealing with callbacks is not keeping a reference to the callback for the life of the callback, e.g. `dll.set_callback(CFUNCTYPE(callback))` instead of the decorator I used.  The object is destroyed right after setting the callback.

Comment: not the exact code, no. As I mentioned I have no influence on the callback (it's a callback inside the debugger context in Pydbg). The important part was the casting and I think you provided all the pointers I need there. So even though it doesn't work out of the box, this will get me where I want to go. Thanks.